# Break statement doesn't break the for loop

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a nested dictionary from a text file, the problem is that the inner loop is taking all the breakpoints in the file when I need it to take only the inline breakpoints, because of this I
added a break statement if is reading into a new line but is not breaking the loop.
I've tried many other formats in the text file but the problem remains.
python code:

```
def create_dictionary(filename):
    units_dict = {}
    courses_dict = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for units in f:
            (unit_key, unit_name) = units.split(" : ")
            for course in unit_name.split(", "):
                (course_key, course_name) = course.split(": ")
                courses_dict[course_key] = course_name

                if '\n' in course:
                    break

            units_dict[unit_key] = courses_dict
    return units_dict
```

text file format:

```
first : initial1: course name1, initial2: course name2
second : initial3: course name3, initial4: course name4
```

output expected:

```
{first:{initial1: course name1, initial2: course name2},
second:{intial3: course name3, initial4: course name4}}
```

actual output:

```
{first:{initial1: course name1, initial2: course name2, intial3: course name3, initial4: course name4},
second:{initial1: course name1, initial2: course name2, intial3: course name3, initial4: course name4}}
```

I pretty new to python so maybe I'm making an stupid mistake, anyway if you can help me I'd really appreciate it.
(I post the code there are similar questions in a different context)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`courses_dict` is aggregating everything and you end up with each entry in `units_dict` referring to the same dictionary. Try this

```
def create_dictionary(filename):
    units_dict = {}
    with open(filename) as f:
        for units in f:
            (unit_key, unit_name) = units.split(" : ")
            # each entry should have a new dict
            courses_dict = {}
            for course in unit_name.split(", "):
                (course_key, course_name) = course.split(": ")
                courses_dict[course_key] = course_name

                if '\n' in course:
                    break

            units_dict[unit_key] = courses_dict
    return units_dict
```